# Problem displaying the text in an angular reusable search component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Everything works great for the create page since it doesn't need to display any value, but the problem is on the edit page, since the edit loads a holidayId and then based on that holidayId I get the therapistId that I send to the component via a subscribe I cannot do it at startup, it is delayed.

Reusable search html:

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-container-icon">
    <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'HOLIDAYS.LIST.INPUTS.THERAPIST_PLACE_HOLDER' | translate }}" (input)="onInput($event.target.value)" [formControl]="searchFormControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)='selectTherapist($event.option.value)'>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option.fullName }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <button *ngIf="isSearching" class="btnPosFix" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="onClear()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-hint align="start">
      {{ 'HOLIDAYS.LIST.INPUTS.THERAPIST_HINT' | translate }}
    </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is the code for the HTML part of the component

Reusable search .ts
and here is the code for the ts part:

```
export class TherapistSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  therapistId: string;
  filteredOptions: Observable<TherapistSearch[]>;
  @Input() selectedTherapistId: string;
  @Input() searchFormControl;
  @Input() isSearching: boolean;
  @Input() isProcessing: boolean;
  @Input() changeFilterSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  @Output() therapistSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() clearInput = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @Output() searchingStateChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() isProcessingChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private therapistService: TherapistService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      forkJoin([
        this.listTherapist()
      ])
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isProcessing = false;
          this.onIsProcessingChanged(this.isProcessing);
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        })
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        const [responseTherapist] = response;
        this.options = responseTherapist.data.map((item) => {
          return new TherapistSearch(`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`, item.id)
        });
        this.filteredOptions = this.searchFormControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith<string | TherapistSearch>(''),
            map((value: string | TherapistSearch) => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.fullName),
            map((fullName: string) => fullName ? this.filter(fullName) : this.options.slice())
          );
        }));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  onInput(value: string) {
    if (!value) {
      this.therapistId = undefined;
    }
  }
  //Emitter
  onClear(): void {
    this.therapistId = null;
    this.searchFormControl.setValue('');
    this.isSearching = false;
    this.onSearchStateChanged(this.isSearching);
    this.clearInput.emit();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  //Emitter
  selectTherapist(event) {
    this.therapistId = event.code;
    this.therapistSelected.emit(this.therapistId);
    this.isSearching = true;
    this.onSearchStateChanged(this.isSearching);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  displayFn(therapist?: TherapistSearch): string | undefined {
    return therapist ? therapist.fullName : undefined;
  }

  private listTherapist(): Observable<ResponseDto<Therapist[]>> {
    return this.therapistService.getAllTherapists();
  }

  filter(fullName: string): TherapistSearch[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      this.normalizeFilter(option.fullName).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.normalizeFilter(fullName).toLowerCase()) > -1);
  }

  normalizeFilter(value: string){
    return value?.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,'');
  }

  //Emitter
  onSearchStateChanged(isSearching: boolean) {
    this.searchingStateChanged.emit(isSearching);
  }

  //Emitter
  onIsProcessingChanged(isProcessing: boolean) {
    this.isProcessingChanged.emit(isProcessing);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sb => sb.unsubscribe());
  }

}
```

Now one of the edit components that use it (how its used):
HTML:

```
                                <kt-therapist-search [searchFormControl]="editForm.get('therapistId')"
                                [isProcessing]="isProcessing"
                                [selectedTherapistId]="therapistId"
                                (isProcessingChanged)="onIsProcessingChanged($event)"></kt-therapist-search>
```

And its .ts (relevant parts):

```
export class EditHolidayComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  isProcessing = true;
  holidayId: string;
  therapistId: string;
  editForm: FormGroup;
  exitDialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmMessageComponent> = null;

  permissions = objectPath.get(PERMISSIONS, 'HOLIDAYS');

  constructor(
    matSnackBar: MatSnackBar,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private editFormBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private applicationHolidayService: HolidaysService,
    public ngxPermissionsService: NgxPermissionsService) {
    super(matSnackBar);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.holidayId = params.id;
        if (this.holidayId)
          this.subscriptions.push(
            forkJoin([
              this.getHoliday()
            ])
              .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                  this.isProcessing = false;
                  this.cdr.detectChanges();
                })
              )
              .subscribe(response => {
                const holidayResponse = response[0];
                if (holidayResponse.isValid) {
                  this.setFormValues(holidayResponse.data);
                  this.therapistId = holidayResponse.data.therapistId;
                }
                else
                  this.openErrorSnackBar(holidayResponse);
              }));
      })
    );
  }
```

I try to set the value via many different ways such as therapistId directly, setValue, setting the options, etc. and nothing seems to work.

When I open the edit page it *does* let me save which means that it does have the Id loaded internally, it's just not displaying the full name on the search box until I click on the clear button, and then select another.

Would greatly appreciate help been on this for hours

Comment: can you add the the all components html and ts file with name at top which are related to this problem. as there is no holidayId in code i'm unable to connect the dots.

Comment: Alright, I did add the related edit holiday component.

Comment: This is a lot of code.  It would make it easier for others to help if you created a [minimal, reproducible exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'll see if I have the time later today and make a quick project that showcases the issue

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I figured out the issue, basically, I was trying to do it via variables and stuff, but in the search itself I had no easy way to tell to update just once exactly when the therapist was acquired in the editholiday.

Refactored the Holiday Get Dto to instead of just give Id it also gives fullname now (API changes), then made the SearchForm an Input as well (Specified its type to FormControl), and in the edit holiday I also added that and linked the variables in the HTML.

Now all that was needed was to just setValue to the searchform inside the edit holiday page as soon as I received the holiday. to the object {fullname, id}.

And it worked.